# Are Dr. Coley's experiments on cancer patients considered unethical today?

Tags: bioethics

Dr.William Coley was one of the first to attempt fever therapy on cancer patients. He did this experiment: artificial erysipelas to treat cancer. Coley injected Streptococcus pyogenes directly into the tumor. My question is: if we repeat this experiment today, ( UNDER THE CONDITION THAT the patient is to be given antibiotics to control the erysipelas), is this experiment/treatment considered ethical?  If it is indeed acceptable within the standards of today's research ethics, is it possible to develop this as a cancer immunotherapy treatment?

Additional question: The Nazis did a lot of medical experiments, and most of them were inhuman and cruel. is it ethical to use data from these experiments?

Comment: There use of Nazi research seems to be a completely separate question... 1 question per question?

Answer (score 1):

The modified version of the proposed experiment, would first need to be proved in culture and possibly mice. More modifications and control, including informed consent may be needed for the experiments to be ethical and acceptable.  After that, an Institutional Review Board (IRB) would need to review the experiment and a trial can then get underway. The IRB may require more data, rigor, control etc., and if the conditions are not met, the experiments may not get underway at all.

> is it possible to develop this as a cancer immunotherapy treatment?

This question might be better at Biology SE. I know you posted it here after you were sent here from there, but the actual aspects of biology, medicine etc., might need lengthy review and discussion. While I am not sure if any modern attempts have been made on treatments with S. pyogenes or something similar in cancer (there is of course the analog of viral therapy for cancer, a field of vigorous research), but you would have to consider things such as antibiotics-resistance, etc.

> Blockquote Additional question: The Nazis did a lot of medical experiments, and most of them were inhuman and cruel. is it ethical to use data from these experiments?

This appears to be a separate question all by itself. I don't know how it would be feasible to use any data that may have resulted from ethically unacceptable trials, since their repeatability is unallowable in ethical settings. You could try to devise modified, ethical versions of those experiments and collect the data freshly, but that would no longer equate to using the data from any Nazi experiments. It would be highly unethical to use any such data, even in meta-analyses or historical reviews if the author(s) don't mention that they were a result of Nazi experiments.